# Populate HTML Form from Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have searched for how to insert items from a MySQL database into a form. From what I understand, for each field, I need to add `value="<?php echo htmlentities($Variable); ?>"` is there a way to insert the fields all at once? Like in a PHP script? Each field already has a name identifier, that's how the insert.php insert the values into the database, like this:

```
    //SQL Query to insert data
$sql="INSERT INTO case_info (Volunteer,CaseShortTitle,CaseNumber,HearingDate...)
VALUES ('$_POST[Volunteer]','$_POST[CaseShortTitle]','$_POST[CaseNumber]','$_POST[HearingDate]'...)
```

and the form fields look like this:

```
<div><input type="text" id="p1f5c" name="CaseShortTitle" class="fieldcontent"><div class="fielderror"></div></div>
```

Then the Submit button goes to this insert.php file

Is there a way to use GET to populate the fields in this manner?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's generally bad practice to input data into your database directly from the `$_POST` variables, you should consider sanitizing them first.

If I understand what you are asking, you can do something like this;

```
<form action="" id="myForm" title="myForm">

        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM case_info LIMIT 1";
        $result = myqsl_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
        <input type="text" id="volunteer" value="<?php echo $row['Volunteer']; ?>"
        <input type="text" id="CaseShortTitle" value="<?php echo $row['CaseShortTitle']; ?>"
        <?php
        } //Close while{} loop
        ?>

</form>
```